# Java Programming: Mouse Listener Problems

Tags: java, swing, mouse-listeners

I am having problems with the mouselistener. I've been trying to fix this for the last hour, and finding any related tutorials but they're all the same, not adding it to the jpanel, but I do not have a jpanel on mine!

ClientApplicationWindow Class:

```
public final void createClientWindow(int height, int width) {
        ClientApplicationWindow clientApplicationWindow = new ClientApplicationWindow();
        MouseEventHandler mouseEventHandler = new MouseEventHandler();
        this.addMouseListener(mouseEventHandler);
        frame.setTitle(Constants.CLIENT_NAME);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(clientApplicationWindow);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

            }
        });
        loadIcon();
        loadCursor();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        clientApplicationWindow.start();
    }
```

MouseEventHandler class:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Clicked X: "+e.getX()+" - Mouse Clicked Y: "+e.getY());
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is when I am clicking anywhere on the form, the console isn't printing the specified line...

Comment: is there any reason that you used addWindowListener?

Comment: Yep, for later use on the game I am creating. That works fine if I make the console print something.

Comment: What is `ClientApplicationWindow`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The runnable method is composed of the game loop, which so far contains the render and fps system.

Answer (score 3):

Without more evidence, this looks werid...

```
ClientApplicationWindow clientApplicationWindow = new ClientApplicationWindow();
MouseEventHandler mouseEventHandler = new MouseEventHandler();
this.addMouseListener(mouseEventHandler);
//...
frame.add(clientApplicationWindow);
```

Assuming that `createClientWindow` is actually within the `ClientApplicationWindow` class, you are creating a new instance of `ClientApplicationWindow`, adding the `MouseListener` to the current instance (`this`) and adding the new instance to the frame...

This would suggest that `this` is not attached to displayable container and therefore not visible on the screen...so it has no way to receive mouse events...

Comment: Yeah I see your point. But when I remove the frame.add(clientApplicationWindow); it brings a createbufferstrategy error. Yes the createClientWindow method is in that class. What would be a better way of adding the instance without the bufferstrategy problem?

Comment: Have you considered using `frame.add(this)` instead?

Comment: Yes I just did the bufferstrategy problem occurs if I don't have the clientApplicationWindow instance. Says Component must have a valid peer.
BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
  
  if(bufferStrategy == null) {
   createBufferStrategy(3);
   return;
  }

Comment: Well, without a runnable example, it's impossible to make an accurate recommendation, but basically, don't create the buffer until after the window has been made displayable

Comment: private synchronized void start() {
  if(running)
   return;
  else {
   running = true;
   thread = new Thread(this);
   thread.start();
  }
 }

Comment: Runnable method:  while (running) {
    render();

Comment: You basically have almost all the render method, the creating the buffer strategy, and graphics disposing and yeah...

Comment: But I have no idea the order in which things are been called or what things are - I'm not a mystic

Comment: When does `createClientWindow` get called in comparison to `start`/`run`/`render`?